# AWS DMS: Table Mapping?

Tags: mysql, aws-aurora, amazon-rds-aurora

We are moving from SQL Server to AuroraDB (mySQL).  Both our source database (SQL Server) and our target (AuroraDB) are on AWS RDS so we are naturally using DMS for the migration.

We make heavy use of synonyms in SQL Server (as I come from an Oracle background) but synonyms are not supported in mySQL.

It is of course not practical to modify tens of thousands of queries (which refer to synonyms) at switchover of the database.

It would be heavenly to make use of "Table Mapping" in AWS DMS.  At least from the name "Table Mapping", it's my assumption that this describes a method of mapping data import from one table name in the source to a different table name in the target.  Unfortunately, I don't see any way to do this in the GUI.  Further, I can't find any mention online of anyone ever trying this, so no examples of the JSON format for writing a mapping rule.

Has anyone out there accomplished this using AWS DMS?

Bonus: Since we have 480+ tables in our source database,  it would be nice to create the mappings in JSON.  It would be nice to know the JSON format for this type of mapping (if possible).

Comment: Please explain what a "synonym" is and show us some examples of your source statement, together with what they need to be converted to.

Comment: As an example, if you have a table named ACCOUNT_INDUSTRY_MAP, you might create a synonym for AIM.  In all CRUD statements, you simply refer to AIM.

Comment: I *think* I found a way to create a table-mapping transformation rule, which will rename the table from its full name to a synonym during real-time data population:

{
    "rules": [
        {
            "rule-type": "transformation",
            "rule-id": "1",
            "rule-name": "1",
            "rule-target": "table",
            "object-locator": {
                "schema-name": "dbo",
                "table-name": "ACCOUNT"
            },
            "rule-action": "rename",
            "value": "ACC",
            "old-value": null
        },
...
    ]
}